# Necessary to specify file types to cache?

Tags: .htaccess, caching

I read that it's important to specify which file types you want to leverage browser caching with. However, what if you're confident you want a similar time-frame for ALL files to cache, can you just set a general command like this?

`.htaccess` code:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access 64 days"
```

That's what I did for my site and it seems to be functioning as I expected (caching everything). Is there anything wrong with doing this instead of specifying each individual file type?

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy to do specific file types without doing a lot of work.
There are some things you might not want to cache like html pages etc. If you update your site, it might not be reflected immediately for some people unless they clear their cache. Most people don' t do that often. Don't be lazy. lol Just do the files that won't change often like `images` etc. One rule get's 5 extensions and more can be added.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|png|js|css)$">
  #expires in 1 month   
  Expires A2592000 
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Well, I liked the sentiment of your answer. I wasn't in a position to edit when I read it previously, and now that I have, this code makes my whole site malfunction. It's not a big deal to me though because I know another way to get the same result this code intends.